# System.Array.SetValue - Object cannot be stored in an array of this type

Tags: c#, .net, spring

I am having problems, please view this link for more info: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-net/issues/59

The component I am using is called Spring Framework .Net it is having a problem with initializing an System.Array of type double with a double[] array, in which is needed before calling a parameter. Value the image I have posted via their GitHub issue section, I have the source code. What can I do to resolve this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MyClass
{
    public static void RunSnippet()
    {
        int argCount = 1;
        object[] values = new object[argCount];
        int i = 0;

        Type elementType = typeof(double);
        object[] argValues = new Object[1];
        double[] arr = new double[] { 9.0, 2.0, 4.0 };

        argValues[0] = arr;

        Break();

        // copy regular arguments
        while (i < argCount - 1)
        {
            values[i] = argValues[i];
            i++;
        }

        Array paramArray = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, argValues.Length - i);

        int j = 0;
        while (i < argValues.Length)
        {
            //paramArray.SetValue(argValues[i++], j++);
            paramArray.SetValue(Convert.ChangeType(argValues[i], argValues[i].GetType()), j);

            i++;
            j++;
        }
        values[values.Length - 1] = paramArray;
    }

    #region Helper methods

    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            RunSnippet();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string error = string.Format("---\nThe following error occurred while executing the snippet:\n{0}\n---", e.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(error);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.Write("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    private static void WL(object text, params object[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(text.ToString(), args);   
    }

    private static void RL()
    {
        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }

    private static void Break() 
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: You can try putting `Convert.ChangeType` in there to convert your value to the `elementType` coming in. That is, `paramArray.SetValue(Convert.ChangeType(argValues[i++], elementType), i++);`. Other than that.. this question is a bit of a bad fit here.. since we don't have any example to test with unless we download Spring and implement what you've implemented (which would take longer than most visitors here can commit).

Comment: Inspect paramArray and argValues[i++] and determine exactly what types they are.  Determine if the value in argValues[i++] is convertible to the type that paramArray is defined as.

Comment: Note that an object[] would need a narrowing conversion to be set into an Array typed as double.  So Simon Whitehead's Convert.ChangeType suggestion should be what you're looking for.

Comment: hello, thank u for responding to my post, what this function does is, it takes parameters that are different type of array values, then assign to the last index in an object array. The problem happens with Array.SetValue method i tried the recommendation u suggested i still get the same error. The sample i created and ran using snippet compiler. u can Google snippet compiler and run this code using snippet compiler. Hopefully someone can help me with this i hope so.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am very very late here, but I hope this helps some one.

Note that the "paramArray" is a double array because of the following lines:

```
Type elementType = typeof(double);
Array paramArray = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, argValues.Length - i);
```

Also, in the while loop, the value of argValues[0] is a double array of { 9.0, 2.0, 4.0 };
So, a "double array" is attempted to add as an item of a double array. You can add only a double value here, not double array.

Changing the type of elementType to double[] should fix the problem.

```
Type elementType = typeof(double[]);
```